# How to set a background image for each monitor in GDM3?

Tags: multiple-monitors, gdm

I have changed my GDM3 background by changing *ubuntu.css*.

```css
#lockDialogGroup {                                                              
/*  background: #2c001e url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);
  background-repeat: repeat; }*/                                                
  background: #000000 url(file:///usr/share/plymouth/themes/trinity/chrono-trinity1920x1080.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

This kind of works, but now the image is displayed in the center of my multi monitor setup.

[image: lockscreen photo]

How do I change this so the image is displayed as a background on every monitor separately instead (like a regular wallpaper)?

Comment: I do not believe gnome can do this without an application or for desktops extension - see https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/different-wallpaper-each-monitor-ubuntu-linux

Comment: That post is about configuring different wallpapers for each monitor after logging in. I don’t want that. I just want the same image to be repeated on each monitor in the GDM lock screen.

Comment: I suggest you create your own image that replicate the image 3 times at the correct size and place. and you just set that big image as the wallparer. Do you follow me ?

Comment: If there is a way to inspect the login screen (similar to an html inspector) or a CSS / element tree reference I’d dive into this myself, but I can’t find any resources on this except existing css files.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? You could probably make it work for the two top monitors by setting the position, size and repeat. But the bottom monitor won't match. For a "real solution" we would need access to the html and be able to add some internal divs (one for each monitor) and css them all separately. I have been looking for a way to do this to accommodate my 2 screens in portrait mode, but it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm currently using a solid color background, but I'm still interested if anyone finds a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a hack than a clean solution. Is there one available ?

My suggestion is to use Gimp to create an image that spans the 3 monitors using the same layout as your monitor.

It is just a matter of 5 minutes, if you know Gimp, a little else, if you don't.

[image: gimp sketch]

This way, you can use whatever you want as wallpaper for each monitor. You are not obliged to use the same image. The final image size is in green.

Comment: This would work assuming I always use the exact same resolutions on those monitors. As your answer states, this is a hack. This might be good enough for some people, but I want a real solution.

Comment: Well, yiu adjust the size of the image to the resolution of you monitor.